# Angular Material Datepicker No Icon in input

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I remove the icon of a datepicker input field:

[image]

Example can be found here: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview
I only find how can I change the icon, but not remove it. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that you cannot remove the icon from the datepicker because that is the way how the datepicker will popup.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can make something like this.

```
.md-datepicker-button {
  display: none;
}
```